# toda vez que vou fazer a inserção dos dados de ' nome, telefone e endereço' , ele pula a primeira opção

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] nome = new String[20];
        String[] endereco = new String[20];
        String[] telefone = new String[20];

        // Loop para preencher com vazio os dados
        for (int i = 0; i < nome.length; i++) {
            nome[i] = "";
            telefone[i] = "";
            endereco[i] = "";
        }

        int cont = 1;
        int opcao = 0, posicao = 0;

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            // quando o usuário fazer a inserção o programa vai perguntar se ele deseja continuar inserindo mais cadastro ou não,
            // caso seja digitado não volte ao menu inicial;

            System.out.println("1 - Inserir \n 2 - Excluir \n 3 - Listar \n 4 - Sair ");
            opcao = ler.nextInt();

            switch (opcao) {
                case 1:
                    if (posicao < nome.length) { // caso a posição seja menor que nomes entre no loop;
                        do {
                            // Quando entra nessa parte ele pula o nome e cai em endereço depois telefone;
                            // caso eu queira continuar preenchendo, ai sim ele permite inserir o nome;
                            System.out.print("Qual o nome da Pessoa : ");
                            nome[posicao] = ler.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Qual o endereço da Pessoa : ");
                            endereco[posicao] = ler.nextLine();
                            System.out.print("Qual o telefone da Pessoa : ");
                            telefone[posicao] = ler.nextLine();

                            System.out.println("Deseja continuar 1 - Sim / 2 - Não");
                            cont = ler.nextInt();

                        } while (cont == 1);
                    }else {

                        System.out.println("Sua agenda está cheia.");
                    }
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("Deseja Continuar no Programa 1 - Sim / 2 - Não");
            cont = ler.nextInt();

        } while (cont == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Consegue se decidir entre java e C++?

Comment: O código todo deve estar formatado como tal

Answer (score -3):

Achei a solução, na hora de fazer o input do valor está assim:

nome[posicao] = ler.nextLine(); dessa forma ele ntende que é um valor inteiro

alterei para nome [posicao]= Integer.parseInt(ler.nextLine()); e tive sucesso na resolução do problema;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).